# Converting float from 0 to 1 to RGB 16bit

Tags: c, embedded

I would like to convert a float to RGB 16bit. The float range is from 0 to 1. The RGB format is 5bits for Red, 6 bits for Green, 5 bits for Blue.
So to clarify more, 0 is fully black and 1 is fully bright.

```
 // dot product 
    if (dp > 0)
                {
                    unsigned short color = color;
                    float intens ;
                    intensity = ambient_light + dp;

                    if (intensity > 1)
                        intensity = 1;
                    if (intensity < 0)
                        intensity = 0;

                    // intensity now varies from 0-1, 0 being black or grazing and 1 being
                    intens= color*intensity;
                    the_object->polys[curr_poly].shade = intens;
           // shade is unsigned short

                } // end if light is reflecting off surface
                else{
                    float color = the_object->polys[curr_poly].color*ambient_light;

                    the_object->polys[curr_poly].shade = color;
                }
            } // end if use flat shading
```

Comment: Post more detail as to your goal.  Posting example inputs/outputs would help.  Posting code that you have tried is even better.  Else this is too broad.

Comment: Not enough information. Is the `float` a representation of the packed `uint16_t`? If so, is it the usual typical arrangement? Or are you saying *each* of the 3 colour components are in the range `0..1`, and need translating to the 5 or 6 bit range to be packed?

Comment: I have a dot product result that is from -1 to 1. I have the color is in 16bits. I'm doing flat shading, so I need the color 16bit, and I want to modulate it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have a dot product from 0 to 1. and I want to modulate the color of a cube using flat shading. The result color is 16bit. so how would I convert that dot product value into shading color value which is 16bit

Comment: First you say -1 to 1 and then you say 0 to 1. But why are you using the 16 bit colour model in year 2016?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm doing it in embedded software, so I have to live with 16bit for LCD

Comment: @WeatherVane It's from 0 to 1

Comment: in this case you are trying to convert grey image to "pseudo color". since color image is a 3d space (2d color +1d brightness), there are arbitrary many ways to do it, called "mapping", such as "grey", "jet", "heat" and so on. if you don't know what to choose from, I recommend  "direct mapping": you just multiply the float with 65535 then convert to 16 bit unsigned int, ugly but simple.

Comment: mapping to grey is also a common solution, but I'm not sure if that's what you want. also color format conversion for a lot of embedded platforms are done in the ISP or display backend. system frame buffer usually remain rgba32 or rgbx32 most of the time, and hardware converts the data to rgb24/666/565 when it's sent to the lcd. so if you are doing this in software, chances are you are doing it wrong, especially your processor seems pretty powerful: it has fpu and it supports parallel lcd display, it should also have a display backend or isp

Comment: @user3528438 I need to convert it to R5G6B5 not float to u16

Comment: like I said, there are many ways to do it. you didn't specify what mapping scheme you want, so i just give you one that i think is easy to implement. so answer this question first: what color and brightness does 0.0 represent, what about 0.5, and 1.0? you need to be clear what you want to receive the solution you want. keyword is both brightness and color.

Comment: Please give some example inputs and required outputs, and show your code attempting to do this, explaining where it has gone wrong.

Comment: 0 is black and 1 is fully bright.

Comment: please add that to the question and I will write an answer

Comment: I have edited the question and I have posted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint16_t floatToRGB565(float input)
{
    uint8_t x = input*255;
    uint8_t r = (x&248u);//0xff-0x07, 5msb mask
    uint8_t g = (x&252u);//0xff-0x03, 6msb mask
    uint8_t b = (x&248u);//0xff-0x07, 5msb mask

    return (r<<8)|(g<<3)|(b>>3);// assuming r is at msb
}
```

live demo: http://ideone.com/npLpB7

Comment: I want to multiply a float from 0 to 1 with color that's 16bit. How would I that too ?

Comment: @احمد  Probably not. Say you multiply 0.5 with 0xffff (full bright), you don't get half bright. Problem is, the carry bit crosses the rgb565 boundary, so you can not do all three channels  with one usual multiply

Comment: @احمد  Easy way to think about it is to decode RGB565 back to 3 8-bit channels or a single float then encode it back to RGB565.

Comment: @احمد  You should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: I can't ask new questions. I'm banned, I don't know why

Comment: should I left right the RGB565 right for each channel then multiply each channel by the float ? then encode it back to RGB565 ?

Comment: I used masks to  decode RGB565 to 3 8 bit channels. How would I encode the result three floats back to RGB565

Comment: @احمد you image is grey, so you can just pick one channel to encode, as they should be the same. however since G channel has more precision, you should prefer over the other two.